# Category meta keyword, description issue in Magento

Tags: magento

Nothing given for meta description for category but some contents are loading.. But from where..?

Comment: which content please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Its taking default configuration meta values. Check your **Admin -> System -> Configuration ->Select current configuration scope to default config in dropdown -> Design -> HTML Head** and change the default meta values...

Comment: But the meta content loading for each category is different apart from the default one in  Admin -> System -> Configuration ->Select current configuration scope to default config in dropdown -> Design -> HTML Head

Comment: But what to do mean by Select current configuration scope to default config in dropdown.?

Comment: If you dont fill meta information, by default magento takes default configurations meta information and other details.

Comment: Then as per statement all the categories should load only the default meta configuration but in my case each category loads with different meta keyword and meta description. Hope you understand what i mean.?

Comment: Can you give me your site url. So that I can check.

Comment: http://stores.vitality4life.com.au/drinking-water-filters. I have given Meta Keyword as Test Keyword and Meta description as Test description. But see the source code what content is loading.?